# How to build a where statement based on dynamic conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

Due to business complexity we had to have a dyanamic conditions table.

Our table is called "Rules"

It has this structure

```
ID  Field        Op        Unit        Value      Discount
==========================================================
1   Gender       =         NULL        Male       0.07
2   Gender       =         NULL        Female     0.08
3   Age          >=        Year        60         0.02
4   Age          =         Year        18         0.09
5   Age          <=        Month       6          0.04
6   Height       <=        NULL        150        0.03
7   Height       >=        NULL        165        0.06
```

I am trying to select only records that match a customers data

```
DECLARE @Gender varchar(10) = 'Male'
DECLARE @Age int = 70 -- In months

SELECT * 
FROM Rules
WHERE (Field = 'Gender' AND Value = @Gender) OR 
(@Age/12 BETWEEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN Field = 'Age' AND Op IN ('=', '>', '>=')  AND Unit = 'Year' THEN (@Age/12)
            ELSE 0
        END
        AND
        CASE 
            WHEN Field = 'Age' AND Op IN ('=', '<', '<=')  AND Unit = 'Year' THEN (@Age/12)
            ELSE 999
        END
)
```

But the problem is with this query I get all rules selected not just the ones that related.

How to adjust it to limit the selection to only related records?

Comment: How do you intend to enter an age of say 3 months? Since the age is given as `int`, you cannot enter `0.25` years. Is the age given in months?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I am going to split the condition into Years and Months another ( 2 case statements)

Comment: What I mean is, what unit does `@Age` have?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Just Year and Month

Comment: So what does `70` mean? 70 years, 70 months, 7 years and 0 months?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes good point. it is in Months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `Value` is a text column. It must converted to a number before comparing ages. I do so in a sub-select.

I also assume that `@Age` is given in months. So if an age of 70 years was given, it would have to be entered as

```
DECLARE @Age int = 12 * 70
```

The age must always be given in the same unit, because the query has no way to determine whether it should compare it as year or month otherwise. E.g. if you enter 5, then if it is a baby of 5 months then a discount of 0.04 applies, but if it is a child of 5 years, then no age discount applies.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *, CASE WHEN IsNumeric(Value)=1 THEN CONVERT(int, Value) ELSE 0 END AS IntValue
   FROM Rules
   ) R
WHERE
    (Field = 'Gender' AND @Gender = Value) OR
    (Field = 'Age' AND Op = '>=' AND
        @Age >= IntValue * CASE Unit WHEN 'Year' THEN 12 ELSE 1 END) OR
    (Field = 'Age' AND Op = '=' AND
        @Age = IntValue * CASE Unit WHEN 'Year' THEN 12 ELSE 1 END) OR
    (Field = 'Age' AND Op = '<=' AND
        @Age <= IntValue * CASE Unit WHEN 'Year' THEN 12 ELSE 1 END);
```

Note also, that I multiply the `IntValue` to convert years into months instead of dividing the age. This is better, because division can lead to rounding errors. With the multiplication we stay in the integer range.

This could be simplified, e.g. by testing the field name for `Age` once, but I think that it is easier to read if every rule is translated separately.

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3df02/11/0